# Feel bad after a Max O2 test - is it normal?

Tags: cardio, hiit, interval-training, tiredness

At work I did a standard Max O2 test on a stationary bike.
In the hours after I didnt feel so good.  Is this normal?
If not, is it likely that I have a low tolerance for exercise?  Or is it just that I am not very used to it?   (Would it be the Biking or the intense exercise?.

Right now, I do not have a high fitness level, but my health is good.  In the past, I feel I always have had problems with exercise, even when I was in good shape.

Comment: What kind of test was it? Was it an unusually high intensity for you?

Comment: 1) Quite standard I think, step-vise increase until I can't continue anymore.  2) Yes (nowadays)

Comment: Did it stop when you felt completly exhausted or when your heart rate reached a specific value? Did you instantly feel worse after?

Comment: (1) Not Specific value - think he just stopped because he saw i could not increase any more.

Comment: (2) Yes - Slowly getting better hour by hour.